# Showing all values on one point on x axis and changing range for rCharts highcharts

Tags: r, highcharts, rcharts

I am just getting into rCharts, and I want to enhance my graphs.

- I would like to change the min/max of my axes in my graph,
- I would also like to show all values per each point on the x-axis
  when I hover over it. Currently, I can only view one data point per x
  axis when I hover over it

Can someone help me show the syntax for it? I would appreciate it very much.

```
library(rCharts)
h <- Highcharts$new()
h$xAxis(categories = c('Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun',
                       'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'))
h$yAxis(list(list(title = list(text = 'Rainfall'))
             , list(title = list(text = 'Temperature'), opposite = TRUE)
             , list(title = list(text = 'Sea Pressure'), opposite = TRUE))
)
h$series(name = 'Rainfall', type = 'column', color = '#4572A7',
         data = c(49.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4))
h$series(name = 'Temperature', type = 'spline', color = '#89A54E',
         data = c(7.0, 6.9, 9.5, 14.5, 18.2, 21.5, 25.2, 26.5, 23.3, 18.3, 13.9, 9.6),
         yAxis = 1)

h$series(name = 'Sea-Level Pressure', type = 'spline', color = '#AA4643',
         data = c(1016, 1016, 1015.9, 1015.5, 1012.3, 1009.5, 1009.6, 1010.2, 1013.1, 1016.9, 1018.2, 1016.7),
         yAxis = 2)
h
```

Answer (score 0):

What have you tried/search so far?

- From http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.max (same Y axis)

  ```
  h$yAxis(
     list(
       list(title = list(text = 'Rainfall'), min = 0),
       list(title = list(text  = 'Temperature'), max = 410, opposite = TRUE),
       list(title = list(text = 'Sea Pressure'), min = 1, max = 2, opposite = TRUE)
      )
   )
  ```
- Not sure if this is what you asking: To **share** tooltip: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/tooltip.shared. Example here: http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/tooltip/shared-true/

  ```
  h$tooltip(shared = TRUE)
  ```

Comment: the tooltip trick worked! I tried to change the tickInterval but it wasn't showing up anything. As for the min,max, I wasn't sure about the appropriate syntax